# Issue in SOAP XML

Tags: ios

I have implemented SOAP Service in iOS.
I am using the following code for sending the request.

```
NSString *sSOAPMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    "<soap:Body>"
    "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/\">"
    "<Celsius>50</Celsius>"
    "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>"
    "</soap:Body>"
    "</soap:Envelope>";


NSURL *sRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sRequestURL];
NSString *sMessageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sSOAPMessage length]];

[myRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[myRequest addValue: @"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[myRequest addValue: sMessageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[myRequest setHTTPBody: [sSOAPMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection ) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}else {
    NSLog(@"Some error occurred in Connection");

}
```

And I am getting following response. Not getting any value i.e. Celsius or Fahrenheit value in response.

Comment: It will returning the web page. With some HTML tags & spans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it works now:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
"<soap:Body>\n"
"<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/\">    <Celsius>25.5</Celsius>                                                      </CelsiusToFahrenheit>"
"</soap:Body>\n"
"</soap:Envelope>\n"
];
NSLog(soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

Then get the response as:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",webData ];

//  NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d, \n %@", [webData length],data);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response is: %@",theXML);
}
```

Afterwords you need to parse it.

Comment: I have changed it but now nothing will return from the server.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your response.... It is started working & returning the response..:) Thanks